# How to use Browser Native Image Lazy Loading to wordpress Galleries?

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, gallery

How to implement browser's native Lazy Loading for Images( `loading="lazy"` ) at Wordpress Galleries using `[gallery]` shortcode ?

Answer (score 0):

put the code below in your theme `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag', 'roka_lazy_load_gallery_images', 99, 4 );
function roka_lazy_load_gallery_images( $output, $tag, $attr, $m ) {

    if( $tag !== 'gallery' ) return $output;

    $output = str_replace( '<img ', '<img loading="lazy" ', $output );

    return $output;
}
```